# Как выбирать случайную клетку в генераторе лабиринта (DFS лабиринт)?

Tags: c#, генерация-случайных-данных

Пишу генератор лабиринтов по методу поиска в глубину. И вместо красивых зигзагов и тупиковых ветвей получаю длинные коридоры, которые иногда меняются. Не понимаю, где ошибка. Мне кажется, что функция выбора случайного соседа работает неправильно, иначе вообще не представляю, где копать.
Код проекта:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Maze
    {
        private readonly Cell[,] _cells;
        private readonly int _width;
        private readonly int _height;
        public Stack<Cell> _path = new Stack<Cell>();
        public List<Cell> _neighbours = new List<Cell>();
        public Random rng = new Random();
        public Cell start;

    public Maze(int width, int height)
    {
        start = new Cell(1, 1, true, true);


        _width = width;
        _height = height;
        _cells = new Cell[width, height];
        for (var i = 0; i < width; i++)
            for (var j = 0; j < height; j++)
                if ((i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 != 0) && (i < _width - 1 && j < _height - 1)) //если ячейка нечетная по х и по у и не выходит за пределы лабиринта
                {
                    _cells[i, j] = new Cell(i, j); //то это клетка (по умолчанию)
                }
                else
                {

                    _cells[i, j] = new Cell(i, j, false, false);
                }
        _path.Push(start);
        _cells[1, 1] = start;
    }

    public void CreateMaze()
    {
        _cells[start.X, start.Y] = start;
        while (_path.Count != 0)
        {
            _neighbours.Clear();
            GetNeighbours(_path.Peek());
            if (_neighbours.Count != 0)
            {
                Random randNum = new Random();
                //randNum.Next(0, _neighbours.Count);
                Cell nextCell = _neighbours[randNum.Next(0, _neighbours.Count)];
                RemoveWall(_path.Peek(), nextCell);
                nextCell.Visit();
                _cells[nextCell.X, nextCell.Y]._isVisited = true;
                _path.Push(nextCell);
            }
            else
            {
                _path.Pop();
            }

        }
    }
    public void DrawGrid()
    {
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < _cells.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            for (var j = 0; j < _cells.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(i, j);
                if (_cells[i, j].IsCell())
                {

                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                else
                {

                    Console.Write("#");
                }
            }

    }
    private void GetNeighbours(Cell localcell) // Получаем соседа текущей клетки
    {

        int x = localcell.X;
        int y = localcell.Y;
        const int distance = 2;
        Cell[] possibleNeighbours = new[] // Список всех возможных соседeй
        {
            new Cell(x, y - distance), // Up
            new Cell(x + distance, y), // Right
            new Cell(x, y + distance), // Down
            new Cell(x - distance, y) // Left
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) // Проверяем все 4 направления
        {
            var s = possibleNeighbours[i];
            if (s.X > 0 && s.X < _width && s.Y > 0 && s.Y < _height)
            {// Если сосед не выходит за стенки лабиринта
                if (_cells[s.X, s.Y].IsCell() && !_cells[s.X, s.Y]._isVisited)
                { // А также является клеткой и непосещен
                    _neighbours.Add(s);
                }// добавляем соседа в Лист соседей
            }
        }

    }

    private Cell ChooseNeighbour(List<Cell> neighbours)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int r = rnd.Next(neighbours.Count);
        return neighbours[r];

    }

    private void RemoveWall(Cell first, Cell second)
    {
        int xDiff = second.X - first.X;
        int yDiff = second.Y - first.Y;
        int addX = (xDiff != 0) ? xDiff / Math.Abs(xDiff) : 0; // Узнаем направление удаления стены
        int addY = (yDiff != 0) ? yDiff / Math.Abs(yDiff) : 0;

        // Координаты удаленной стены
        _cells[first.X + addX, first.Y + addY]._isCell = true;
        _cells[first.X + addX, first.Y + addY]._isVisited = true;
        second.Visit();
        //_path.Push(second);
        _cells[second.X, second.Y] = second;

    }
}
}
```

Структура ячейки

```
public struct Cell
{

public int X { get; set; }
public int Y { get; set; }
public bool _isCell { get; set; }
public bool _isVisited { get; set; }

public Cell(int x, int y, bool isVisited = false, bool isCell = true)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
    _isCell = isCell;
    _isVisited = isVisited;
}

public void Visit() //Функция посещения ячейки
{
    _isVisited = true;

}

public Cell ToWall(Cell curCell) //Функция смены типа ячейки
{
    curCell._isCell = false;

    return curCell;
}

public Cell ToCell (Cell curCell)
{
    curCell._isCell = true;
    curCell._isVisited = false;
    return curCell;
}

public bool IsCell()
{
    if (_isCell == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

Исполняемый код

```
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Maze maze = new Maze(20, 20);
            maze.CreateMaze();
            maze.DrawGrid();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Забавный у вас метод `IsCell()`, хех, почему просто не `public bool IsCell() => _isCell;`? Хотя вообще не пойму для чего он, можно ведь и просто `_isCell`, метод лишний получается...

Comment: Да хотел сперва организовать доступ к внутренним полям методами, а потом забил и открыл их для редактирования.

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался.
Я каждый раз инициализировал новую переменную рандома и соответственное, она каждый раз генерила одинаковое число. Вынес объявление переменной из цикла и все заработало.